# Package conventions for MVC app

Tags: java, coding-standards, mvc, packages

Which (if either) of the below is the more conventional/acceptable way to structure packages in a J2EE app? I'm trying to follow an MVC pattern as much as possible.

- foo.bar.users

  - foo.bar.users.servlets
  - foo.bar.users.DAO
  - foo.bar.users.Entity
- foo.bar.orders

  - foo.bar.orders.servlets
  - foo.bar.orders.DAO
  - etc...

or

- foo.bar.DAO

  - foo.bar.DAO.users
  - foo.bar.DAO.orders
  - ...
- foo.bar.servlets

  - foo.bar.servlets.users
  - foo.bar.servlets.orders
  - ...

Comment: Hi Chris C, naming/organization recommendations are off-topic here: the only thing that matters is agreement amongst your team.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the second option, for me it have more sense to store package as the architeture model (MVC) and not favour an arrangement based on your specific application logic.